# Read and process data files from folder, add column based on filename and merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-processing

I have .csv files in a folder for 10 different people. The files are named "data_m1", "data_m2", etc. I want to create a for loop to read all the files, process them by applying certain functions and creating new columns as features, then merge them to one file efficiently. In the process, I want to read the filename and add the column "name" and label the data according to filenames "m1", "m2", etc.

let's say I want to apply this simple process which creates a new column for each 10 files in the folder

```
df['new_column1']= df['value'].apply(lambda x:  1 if 0 < x <= 10 else 2 if 10 <x<20 else np.nan)
```

Then, I want to combine all files into one dataframe at the end but labeling them with name column by the extensions "m1" , "m2" ,etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd


# create an empty list to append DataFrames
dfs = []
# use glob to get a list of file names and iterate
for file in glob.glob('/path/to/folder/data_m*.csv'):
    # read the file
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # assign the name column based on the file name
    df['name'] = os.path.splitext(file)[0].split('_', 1)[1]
    # do more stuff here
    # append df to the empty list
    dfs.append(df)

# concat all your frames together
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: You can replace the user function by `pd.cut`. Something like: `df['new_column1'] = pd.cut(df['value'], bins=[0, 10, 20], labels=[1, 2])`